# Как сделать прозрачный TitleBar в окне (XCode, Swift, Cocoa)

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, cocoa

Не могу понять как сделать так, чтобы как в приложенном примере (Калькулятор).
Т.е. чтобы можно было изменить цвет заголовка (или, возможно, добавить свои контролы на него?!)

Прочитал, вроде это теперь делается через User Defined Runtime Attributes, вот указал их, но вроде ничего не изменилось. Что делаю не так? Спасибо!

[image: Calculator & Runtime Attributes]

Answer (score 1):

Мне помог этот код (Swift 2.0):

```
    view.window?.titleVisibility = .Hidden
    view.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    view.window?.styleMask |= NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask
    view.window?.movableByWindowBackground = true
```